# Does calling retrofit 2 in ViewModel can cause memory leak?

Tags: android, retrofit2, viewmodel

The question is brief: Calling retrofit 2 asynchronous using a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) can cause memory leaks?

Like the following example.

**ShowsAsynViewModel.java**

public class ShowsAsyncViewModel extends ViewModel {

```
private static final String TAG = "ShowsAsyncViewModel";

private MutableLiveData<List<Show>> shows;

public LiveData<List<Show>> getShows() {
    if (shows == null) {
        shows = new MutableLiveData<>();
        loadShows();
    }
    return shows;
}

private void loadShows() {
    // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(TvMazeService.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    TvMazeService service = retrofit.create(TvMazeService.class);
    service.getShows().enqueue(new Callback<List<Show>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Show>> call, Response<List<Show>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<Show> showList = response.body();
                if (showList != null) {
                    shows.setValue(showList);
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: Error code: " + response.code() + " - error message: " + response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Show>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: Failed to connect: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
}
```

**RetrofitActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrofit);

    ShowsAsyncViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ShowsAsyncViewModel.class);
    model.getShows().observe(this, new Observer<List<Show>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Show> shows) {
            // Do something with the result
        }
    });
}
```

Here is what I noticed.

1. If I call retrofit 2 with this same method but in RetrofitActivity.java onCreate method. I end up with a huge memory leak because retrofit will be called every time the activity is recreated.
2. If I call retrofit 2 using a private static inner class holding a WeakReference to the context I do not get memory leaks because of the WeakReference and also because this method is not called multiple times if the user rotates the screen multiple times.
3. Using this ShowsAsyncViewModel I did not get a memory leak, probably because this method is called only once, even though if the user rotates the screen multiple times. I would like to be sure that this will not cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can cause a memory leak. 
Imagine a scenario in which you make a network call from the `ViewModel` attached to your `Activity`. Before the call is completed the activity is destroyed not for a configuration change but by calling `finish()`. 
Even though both the Activity and ViewModel are destroyed the call will continue to execute.

To prevent this you can modify your `ShowsAsynViewModel.java` as follows (kotlin code)

```
// Glogal variable
private lateinit var getShowsNetworkCall: Call<List<Show>>

void loadShows() {
    // You can add parameters to the call here
    getShowsNetworkCall = service.getShows()
    getShowsNetworkCall.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Show>>) {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Trip>>, response: Response<List<Trip>>) {...}
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Show>>, t: Throwable) {...}
    }
}

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()

    getShowsNetworkCall?.cancel()
}
```